# How do you clear the drive cache in Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, memory, cache

I am developing an I/O bound application, and I am trying to track down a bug that occurs when reading from slow moving drives.  The problem with tracking down this Heisenbug is that something - the drive or Windows itself, caches the read in ram somewhere (either in the drives in-built cache, or somewhere in the OS).

To see the bug in my software, I have to reboot my system (running inside a VM has the same performance problem - I read the data once, and it ends up cached somewhere.)

Is there a way to clear any of these caches (be they in the OS or drive itself)?

Comment: Why is allowing the system to read once from the drive, and thence from the cache, not suitable?

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I am trying to find a race condition that only occurs in slow reads.  reading from the cache is not inducing the race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [clear the Windows StandbyList/Cache](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/858673/Empty-Standby-List-in-Windows) by calling the Windows API call *NtSetSystemInformation*.

On [stackoverflow someone posted a different hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7701908/1466046) to clean system cache, maybe this is what you need.

Comment: Found my bug because of this.  Don't use threads if you don't need to, kids.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Win32 IO calls? If so, use the `FILE_FLAG_NOBUFFERING` option on your `CreateFile` call. Then all `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` calls will go straight to the hardware, with no buffering or cacheing in the OS. A limitation: Your read and write calls through that file handle have to be in multiples of the block size, and your offset-in-file must also be in multiples of the block size.

This will not (afaik) stop cacheing on the drive hardware.

Comment: My application is too far removed from the native OS calls to take advantage of this without ... well ...  rewriting it in a different language; but I will keep this in mind if I am ever in c(++) land with a similar problem.

Comment: I  was afraid that might be the case, but thought it would be good to put it out there.